# How to capture THIS year in a SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm looking for a way to let SQL display data from the year we're in. 
On my page the data is displayed like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date > '01.01.2014'  (European date style)
```

But when we move over to 2015 I have to change the code to display that years data.
So I was thinking that perhaps SQL have some magic function that lets me display data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date = 'this.year'
```

Tried searching the web/Google for answers, but I couldn't find a good way to write the question in a single and understandable sentence.

Comment: mysql's native date-as-string format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. if you're storing your dates as varchar, and some OTHER format, like your bass-ackwards euro format, then you can NOT use `>` and `<` type operations on those strings. YOu should be storing dates in date/datetime fields

Comment: Sorry Marc B, I didn't make up the national rules of setting date formats. Have to stick to the format that we use. But I do use current_timestamp to set the date on insert. Thanx for replying, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`year`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE year(date) = year(now());
```

A more advanced way is to avoid the function on `date`.  This allows the use of an index:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE date >= makedate(year(now()), 1) and
      date < makedate(year(now()) + 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE year(date) = year(curdate())
```